# Obtener última ID Insertada

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código para añadir un libro a la base de datos.

```
    if(count($_POST)>0){
    $a = new SQLMan();
    $a->tablename = "libro";
    $numpag = "0";
    $year = "0";
    // $a->in_test = true;
    $a->isbn = $a->is_string($_POST["isbn"]);
    $a->titulo = $a->is_string(ucwords(mb_strtolower($_POST["titulo"])));
    $a->subtitulo = $a->is_string(ucwords(mb_strtolower($_POST["subtitulo"])));
    $a->num_pag = $a->is_string($numpag);
    $a->anio = $a->is_string($year);
    $a->editorial_id = $a->is_string($_POST["editorial_id"]);
    $a->autor_id = $a->is_string($_POST["autor_id"]);
    $a->add();

    $lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID($a);

        echo $lastid
```

Y me haría falta sacar el ID pero al usar LAST_INSERT_ID() me tira este error:

`Call to undefined function LAST_INSERT_ID()`

¿Hay algo que este haciendo mal? Gracias!

Clase SQLMan

```
Class SQLMan {
    public $tablename;
    public $fields = array();
    public $sql = "";
    public $in_test = false;
    public $lastid;


    public function __set($key,$data){
        $this->fields[$key]=$data;
    }

    public function fields_to_array(){
        return $this->fields;
    }

    public function add(){
        $this->sql = "";
        $this->sql .= "insert into ".$this->tablename." ";
            $d1="";
            $d2="";
            $n=0;
        foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
            $d1 .= $key;
            $d2 .= "$value";
            if($n<count($this->fields)-1){
                $d1 .=",";
                $d2 .=",";
            }
                $n++;
        }
        $this->sql .= "($d1) value ($d2)";

        if($this->in_test){
        echo $this->sql;
        }else{
            return Executor::doit($this->sql);
            return $lastid = $this->insert_id;
        }
    }

    public function update($data,$where=""){
        $this->sql = "update ".$this->tablename." set";
            $d1="";
            $d2="";
            $n=0;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $d1 .= $key."=".$value;
            if($n<count($data)-1){
                //$d1 .= $key."=\"".$value."\"";
                 $d1 .=",";
            }
                $n++;
        }
        $this->sql .= " $d1 ";
        if($where!=""){
            $this->sql .=" where ".$where;
        }

        if($this->in_test){
        echo $this->sql;
        }else{
            return Executor::doit($this->sql);
        }
    }

    public function is_string($v){ return "\"$v\"";}

    // $type default = many, optional = one
    public function select($type="",$fieldx="", $where="",$order="",$limit=""){
        $this->sql = "select ";
        if($fieldx ==""){ $this->sql .= "*" ; }else{ $this->sql .= $fieldx ; }
        $this->sql .= " from ".$this->tablename;
        if($where!="") { $this->sql .= " where ".$where ;}
        if($order!="") { $this->sql .= " order by ".$order ;}
        if($limit!="") { $this->sql .= " limit ".$limit ;}
        if($this->in_test){
            echo $this->sql;
        }else{
            if($type=""){$type="many"; }
            return Selector::process($type,$this->sql,$this);
        }


    }

    }


}
```

Executor:

```
<?php

    class Executor {

        public static function doit($sql){
            $con = Database::getCon();
            return array($con->query($sql),$con->insert_id);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Database código

```
<?php
/// evilnapsis.tk evilnaps 6RSk!IpTJ]vv
class Database {
    public static $db;
    public static $con;
    function Database(){
        $this->user="root";$this->pass="";$this->host="localhost";$this->ddbb="library";
//      $this->user="minedeck_mduser";$this->pass="l00lapal00za";$this->host="localhost";$this->ddbb="minedeck_md";
    }

    function connect(){
        $con = new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->ddbb);
        return $con;
    }

    public static function getCon(){
        if(self::$con==null && self::$db==null){
            self::$db = new Database();
            self::$con = self::$db->connect();
        }
        return self::$con;
    }

}
```

Comment: como tienes tu conexión? es decir tu clase `SQLMan()`de donde sale? es una librería o tu la declaraste?

Comment: Sería una libreria exterior que estoy usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `mysqli`deberías usar lo que ya tienes en el método `doit()` de la clase `Executor`:

```
$con->insert_id;
```

Pues se accede a través de una propiedad, no de un método:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php

Fíjate que esa clase devuelve un array con el `id` que puedes recuperar, tras pasar por varios `return`, como:

```
list($rs,$lastid)=$a->add();
```

En vez de:

```
 $a->add();
 $lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID($a);
```

Te paso una versión simplificada de tu código para que compruebes su funcionamiento:

```
<?php

$a = new SQLMan();
list($rs,$lastid)=$a->add();
echo $lastid;

class SQLMan {
    public function add(){
        $this->sql="
            INSERT INTO libros (titulo)
              VALUES ('Platero y yo');
        ";
        return Executor::doit($this->sql);
    }   
}
class Executor {
    public static function doit($sql){
        $con = Database::getCon();
        return array(
            $con->query($sql),
            $con->insert_id
        );
    }
}
class Database {
    public static $db;
    public static $con;
    function Database(){
        $this->user="root";$this->pass="";
        $this->host="localhost";
        $this->ddbb="stackoverflow";
    }
    function connect(){
        $con = new mysqli($this->host,
            $this->user,$this->pass,$this->ddbb);
        return $con;
    }
    public static function getCon(){
        if(self::$con==null && self::$db==null){
            self::$db = new Database();
            self::$con = self::$db->connect();
        }
        return self::$con;
    }
}
```

Y del dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE libros(
  id_libro int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  titulo varchar(64)
  );
INSERT INTO libros (titulo)
  VALUES ('Platero y yo');
SELECT * FROM libros;
```

Comment: A dónde lo intenta recuperar no es el contexto de una clase sino una instancia entonces this no funcionaria ahí

Comment: Efectivamente. Aunque, si esa variable `$lastid` fuera una propiedad pública de la clase, ya podría ser visible desde fuera con `$a->lastid`

Comment: Exacto David de esa forma claro que sí

Comment: @DavidJP Lo he probado pero no funciona con insert_id

Comment: Era lo que comentábamos @BetaM y yo. ¿Dónde has usado `insert_id`? ¿En el método `add()` o fuera? Es posible que tengas que bucear un poco más en `SQLMan` a ver cómo está accediendo a los datos

Comment: He probado añadiendo a la clase SQLMan public $lastid; y en la funcion add() he añadido esto: return Executor::doit($this->sql);
   return $lastid = $this->insert_id; @DavidJP luego en el front he probado echo $a->lastid; pero nada

Comment: @DavidJP He añadido la clase SQLMan en la pregunta

Comment: Perfecto, mucho más claro así... aunque, fíjate: esa clase utiliza métodos estáticos de otra clase `Executor` que igual podemos ampliar para que devuelva el dato que necesitas en vez de lo que sea que devuelve ahora

Comment: @DavidJP Y como lo ampliaria para añadirle esa funcion?

Comment: Añade la clase `Executor` a tu pregunta y vamos a ver cómo está hecha. Supongo que en el return del método `doit()`, en vez de verdadero, igual podemos colar el número de id

Comment: Ya la he añadido @DavidJP a la pregunta. Lo que si me haría falta devolver el TRUE tambien para validar las inserciones antes de continuar. Por lo que veo el executor tiene lo se insert_id... Pero no sabría como sacarlo igualmente

Comment: Ah, pero si ya lo tenías... sólo te queda recuperar el dato, modifico la respuesta para que lo veas. Pruébalo y me cuentas...

Comment: @DavidJP He probado modificando lo que me pones y al hacerle eco al $lastid me devuelve 0, no la id

Comment: Pues tenemos que seguir buceando... añade el código de esa clase `Database` con su método `getCon()`, porque aguas arriba, salvo esos dos `return` que has puesto, no hay nada con mala pinta

Comment: @DavidJPYa he añadido el código de la database

Comment: @CharlieClewer he comprobado la respuesta y es funcional (adjunto el código simplificado), el error tiene que estar en otro sitio, ¿tal vez algún nombre incorrecto de campo o el de la tabla y no te inserta ningún dato?

Comment: @DavidJP Vale perdona ahora revisando he visto que habia un error que habia dejado en las pruebas de porque no iba... Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!